# Creating a login box in html

Tags: php

hello all I am trying to make a login box on top of my html page, I am using php because if the user logged in then i ll display "Welcome, (his username)" else I would display username and password. Her is the code:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
```

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["$username"]))
{
     print "&lt;div class=\"login\"&gt;Welcome, $username &lt;br/&gt;&lt;font Style=\"font-size:12px;\"&gt;&lt;a href=\"edit.php\"&gt;Edit Account&lt;/a&gt; | &lt;a href= \"log_out.php \"&gt;Logout&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/font&gt;";
}

else
{

    print "div class=\"login\"&gt;
    &lt;form method=\"post\" action=\"login.php\"&gt;
    Username:&lt;input type=\"text\" size=\"30\" name=\"username\"/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
    Password:&lt;input type=\"password\" size=\"30\" name=\"password\"/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;font Style=\"font-size:12px;\"&gt;&lt;a href=\"forgotpass.html\"&gt; forgot  password? &lt;/a&gt; | &lt;a href= \"register.html \"&gt;Register&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\" class=\"right\"/&gt;
    &lt;/form&gt;";
 }

 ?&gt;
```

the output is kind of weird if you execute this on .php file like the login is suppose to be a button but it turns out to be a text and the else if getting printed. Can anyone tell me of any alternative?

Comment: disregard &lt; and &gt; imagine them they are < and >

Comment: ok after removing the quotes...it went well,but the issue is that it is printing  "else { " and in the end ";?>

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&gt;` and `$lt;` (text search and replace) with `<` and `>` or decode your php strings using [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

You must change equivalent < >(html safe symbols) on special characters <>. For example:

```
echo '<div class=\"login\">Welcome, $username <br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your point without having a database but...
Try this [tutorial](http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/php/how-to-make-a-login-system-with-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `&gt; and $lt;` Replace them with `< and >`

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["$username"])) {
     echo '<div class="login">Welcome, '.$username.' </div><font style="font-size:12px;"><a href="edit.php">Edit Account</a> | <a href="log_out.php">Logout</a></font>;';
    } else {

    echo '<div class="login">
            <form method="post" action="login.php">
                Username:<input type="text" size="30" name="username"/><br/>
                Password:<input type="password" size="30" name="password"/><br/>
                <font Style="font-size:12px;"><a href="forgotpass.html"> forgot  password? </a> | <a href= "register.html ">Register</a></font><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="right"/>
            </form>
        </div>';

    }

 ?>
```